# JavaScript Variable Passed onClick to Function is Undefined

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to write a simple vote script with PHP, JavaScript, and MySQL.  When passing the variable from the href onclick paramenter to the javascript function I get an 'undefined' error, I believe referring to the variable.

My PHP looks like this:

```
echo "<td class=\"uparrow\"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"upVote.call(". $row['serial'] ."); return false;\">&#8689;</a></td>";
```

Which generates HTML like this:

```
<td class="uparrow"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="upVote.call(16); return false;">&#8689;</a>
```

And the function looks like this:

```
function upVote(str) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("report_status").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","up_vote.php?serial="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

When the upVote(str) function calls the up_vote.php, the variable is not being passed to PHP for some reason.

The upVote PHP looks like this and functions fine when access directly through a URL:

```
<?php
// Create Connection
$dbconnect=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","user","pass","table");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
//  echo "Connection Sucessful<BR><BR>";
}

// escape variables for security
if (isset($_GET['serial']))
{
    $serial = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect, $_GET['serial']);
}

// define SQL call and fetch the result
$sql = "SELECT vote FROM urls WHERE serial = $serial";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql);

if (!$result) {
  die('Select Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbconnect));
}
//echo $sql . "<BR>"; // for error checking the SQL call

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $return = $row['vote']+1;
    }

echo $return;  //Send result back to javascript

//Update the vote count in the database
$sql = "UPDATE urls SET vote=$return WHERE serial = $serial";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql);

if (!$result) {
  die('Update Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbconnect));
}

mysqli_close($dbconnect);
?>
```

Comment: Is that all that you have in your PHP file? If so, you need to access the parameter with `$_GET['serial']`

Comment: Why are you doing `upVote.call()` ? that's not how that method works. just do `upVote(16)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either don't use call or use it the way it's intended. In this case, I think you should not use it.

The call method is not like "call" from some older languages that used it to invoke subroutines and the like. You don't use "call" to invoke a function normally, you simply use parenthesis. If `abc` is a function `abc()` calls the function and `abc(123)` passes 123 as the first argument.

`call` in javascript is used to call one function with a (typically) different object as the "thisArg" or `this`. You can think of it as being able to `apply` some external function to your object. In fact, there is a companion method `apply`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

```
<td class="uparrow"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="upVote(16); return false;">&#8689;</a>
```